# Object Oriented Programming in Python: How do I execute it without creating the data for it from within the program?

Tags: python, class, oop

A dilemma I am having which illustrates my naivety when it comes to OOP is basic file parsing.  Most examples online stop short of actually implementing the example, which is where I am stuck.
For instance, with an example taken from this website (https://www.biostars.org/p/710/):
This basic code is written:

```
class FastaSeq:

        def __init__(self, name, sequence):

            self.name = name
            self.sequence = sequence
        def get_seqs(file):
            items = []
            index = 0
            for line in file:
                if line.startswith(">"):
                    if index >= 1:
                        items.append(aninstance)
                    index+=1
                    name = line[:-1]
                    seq = ''
                    aninstance = FastaSeq(name, seq)
                else:
                    seq += line[:-1]
                    aninstance = FastaSeq(name, seq)
            yield(aninstance)
```

My very naive question is, how do I get it working?  All examples I see online begin with creating the data on the spot and feeding it into the program, but how do I implement it without doing that?

Comment: Please indent your code properly as code. I've fixed it this time, but you should learn how to use the interface: select the code you pasted, then click the `{}` button.

Comment: (Actually, it looks like mine was the 5th of 6 edits to fix your code, so… at this point, for all I know, there may have been a significant `IndentationError` in your real code that we've now hidden… Even more reason to be careful in posting questions.)

Comment: Meanwhile, if your `get_seqs` is a method of `FastaSeq`, it needs a `self` parameter before `file`. If not, it needs to be dedented so it doesn't come underneath `FastaSeq`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your big problem is a pair of indentation errors you presumably added while copying this program in from the website.

First, you've got `get_seqs` indented under the `class FastaSeq` definition. This makes it a method of the `FastaSeq` class, which it's almost certainly not supposed to be. (If it *is* supposed to be a method, then its `file` parameter is going to be filled by the `self` object when you try to call it, which seems both misleading and useless.) So, you need to dedent `get_seqs` back to the left column.

Second, you've got `yield(aninstance)` dedented outside of the `for` loop. So, each time through the loop, you create a new `FastaSeq` object, then store it in `asinstance`, overwriting the previous one, then do nothing with it; at the end, you yield just the last one. You almost certainly wanted to yield *all* of them, not just the last one, so you need to indent that `yield` to the same position as the `if` and `else`.

Once you've fixed both of those problems, the way to use it is to just call the `get_seqs` function with a filename. That will give you an iterator of `FastaSeq` objects, which you can loop over, or store in a `list`, or whatever else you want to do. For example:

```
with open('myfile.dat') as f:
    instances = list(get_seqs(f))
```

… or …

```
with open('myfile.dat') as f:
    for instance in get_seqs(f):
        print("Here's an instance for you:", instance)
```

Or, putting it together with the question that this answer came from (and fixing a couple of obvious mistakes in that question):

```
with open(input_file) as in_file, open(output_file, 'w') as out_file:
    fasta_sequences = get_seqs(in_file)
    for name, sequence in fasta_sequences:
        new_sequence = some_function(sequence)
        write_fasta(out_file, name, new_sequence)
```

Comment: Yes, an all around bad question.  Thanks for all of your time.  But due to my poor example and poor web-input skills, the point of my question was unfortunately lost.  Although this works for retrieving an instance, what if I wanted to retrieve 'name' or 'sequence'?

Comment: @Vince: I don't think I understand that followup. In your constructor, you've stored `name` and `sequence` as attributes of the `FastaSeq` object. So, you can just do `for fasta in fasta_sequences:` and then `name, sequence = fasta.name, fasta.sequence`. Is there some more complicated problem than this?